# How to substring 0 to 30, but only if there is over 30 characters

Tags: string, flutter, substring

I have a little problem, I want to substring a String, to max 30 characters, but when I do `string.substring(0, 30)`, it works fine if the string is 30+ characters, but if not, it comes with an error.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Can you show me current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting *"RangeError: Value not in range: 30"* error.

Try to add a **length control** before that.

```
if (string.length < 30)

  return string;

else

  return string.substring(0, 30);
```

Let's shorten the code above:

```
String resultText = (string.length < 30) ? string : string.substring(0, 30);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import 'dart:math';
string.substring(0, min(30, string.length));
```

[image]

In the above picture, you can see that 2 variables `below30` and `above30`

```
substring(int start, [int? end]);
```

when we use like this `below30.substring(0,30)`
we get `RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..15: 30`
error.Becasue `below30` length is `15`.`above30` will give proper result because it have `32` character.

**so overcoming this problem You can use like this:**

```
string.substring(0, min(30, string.length));
```

`min(num a, num b)`=> Returns the lesser of two numbers. num (abstract class) may `double` or `int`.so here we didn't get any error `invalid range`.

[image]

For easy use you can use `below30.characters.take(30)` no more complexity.
@@atreeon.

for bulk data manipulation `substring` method will much faster than `take`method

```
Build time: 3812 ms
Time substring: 391 ms, Time take: 1828 ms

Build time: 4172 ms
Time substring: 406 ms, Time take: 2141 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

a bit shorter and without a check

```
string.characters.take(30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
return string.substring(0, string.length < 30 ? string.length : 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

import 'dart:math';
string.substring(0, min(30, string.length));